# How do I get nothingness in succubox

Tags: succubox

I need it to start my own business but I don't have enough nothingness and have no idea how to get it. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Nothingness is gained by buying and opening boxes. To use nothingness in crafting, you need to craft using two fabricators. Other conscience areas can be unlocked by answering a 'honest' answer, or trying to hack the game. Nothingness can also be crafted with a soul to unlock Hard Mode

Comment: I think it's actually if you open a box that contains nothing